# How to pass state in React from one class to another?

Tags: javascript, arrays, reactjs, ecmascript-6, state

I am building a web app with React using ES6 classes. I have an IndexPage.js file which adds data to a database and AdminLandingPage.js file which reads back all data currently in the database in it's componentDidMount() function.

Basically both are working separate now. I want to be able to save data in a state (an array) in IndexPage and then pass that state over to the other file where I can check if the array has data in it and set the state of the table (thus allowing me to not have to refresh the page).

IndexPage has this in it's constructor:

```
constructor(props) {
    super(props);

    this.state = {newbugs: []};
}
```

Here I am adding the data to the database and setting the state of the newbugs array:

```
addBug = (newBug) => {
  BugsApi.addBugData(newBug, data => {
    this.setState({newbugs: data})
  })
}
```

In my AdminLandingPage constructor I have:

```
constructor(props) {
    super(props);

    this.state = {bugs: []};
}
```

And componentDidMount() function where I am reading back all data currently in the database:

```
componentDidMount() {

    BugsApi.getBugData(data => {
      this.setState({bugs: data})
    })
}
```

^ This is where I would like to pass in the newbugs state array from my IndexPage check if it's got data in it and then update the bugs state array in this class.

Let me know if I can be more clear with my question. I have been stuck for hours on this now. Thanks!

Comment: you should read the docs, this is like react 101 stuff here I just googled your exact question word for word and got this: https://facebook.github.io/react/tips/communicate-between-components.html

Comment: Your Read and write operation to DB is seperate. First you are adding to DB in indexPage and then you are fetching from DB in AdminPage.

Say, you don't have DB, and you got response from API and have set the response date to indexPage state variable, now you have to use indexPage state variable into adminPage. How will you achieve this?? This is what we are stuck in

Answer (score 6):

`state` should be passed between components as `props`. For example:

```
class IndexPage extends React.Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    this.state = {newbugs: []};
  }

  ...

  render() {
    return (
      <AdminLandingPage bugs={this.state.newBugs}/>
    )
  }
}

class AdminLandingPage extends React.Component {

  ...

  componentDidMount() {
    // `newBugs`constant holds the bugs passed down from IndexPage
    const newBugs = this.props.bugs;
    BugsApi.getBugData(data => {
      this.setState({bugs: data})
    })
  }

  ...
}
```

Here `IndexPage` passes `state.newBugs` down to it's child component `AdminIndexPage` as the `bugs` prop

Comment: in this example you are passing the state around. I agree generally with what your saying but that first sentence is misleading. 'State should be passed between components as props" would be clearer

Comment: Only problem with this is I don't want to render the admin page inside the index page. If I were to place `<AdminLandingPage bugs={this.state.newBugs}/>` where you have it, it would render the entire component inside it.

Comment: Then it sounds like a data management library like redux could help you.
In redux you essentially have one `state` for the whole app.
I really recommend https://egghead.io/courses/getting-started-with-redux by Dan Abromov, the creator of redux.

Comment: But how to pass more than one state to another class?

Answer (score 0):

I mostly agree with the code that was provided by Red Mercury, with the exception of then setting the state inside of your AdminLandingPage. Once the props are available inside the component, you won't need state in the AdminLandingPage component unless there is something else you are trying to do that wasn't mentioned.

```
class IndexPage extends React.Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    this.state = {newbugs: []};
  }

  render() {
    return (
      <AdminLandingPage bugs={this.state.newBugs}/>
    );
  }
}

const AdminLandingPage = (props) {
  console.log(props.bugs); 
  return (
    ...
  );
}
```

Comment: Is there any way I can do this without rendering the admin page inside indexpage? I just want to pass props but not render the component.

Comment: The best way to do that (which has a big learning curve, depending how comfortable you are with React) is with Redux. Redux is a great way to manage the application state of a React App.